# How to add spacing between TD columns in a table?

Tags: html, css

I am fixing up an email that uses tables, and I am trying to add buttons within `td` tags. The problem I am facing is that no matter what I try, I cannot seem to get spaces between each button. Here is how it looks like right now:

[image]

And here is the HTML that generates it (it's a it repetitive):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="button">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="max-width: 240px; min-width: 120px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0;">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="button">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="max-width: 240px; min-width: 120px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0;">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Not sure how to fix this, no spaces are added no matter what I try.

---

Edit: Got it working, thank you!

[image]

Comment: Why don't you factor all those identical `style` tags to just one? It would make your code more readable and less-prone to errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `border-collapse` property to `collapse`. Change it to `separate` and then add some `border-spacing`:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="button">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="max-width: 240px; min-width: 120px; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px 0; padding: 0;">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="button">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="max-width: 240px; min-width: 120px; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px 0;  padding: 0;">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it still doesn't work. I even added `cellspacing="0"`, still no dice. Not sure whats happening, theres no CSS rules in place that could be overriding this + this is inline styling anyway! So confused

Comment: You gave me the closest starting point. Got it working, made an edit in my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you had was a nested tables. Here is the fixed code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="button">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="button">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://facebook.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding: 12px 24px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -khtml-border-radius: 4px;" bgcolor="#E9703E">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 17px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 120%;">Verify ORCiD</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```